# Can we merge $PATH and $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

Tags: ros, path, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to know if it is possible to add stuff in the $PATH variable to $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH? Actually i want to do this because i have already installed some debian packages on Ubuntu (11.1) which were required by the OpenHaptics toolkit (ver 3.0) but ROS can't find them. If i run the OpenHaptics example directly, it works. But when i try to run some OpenHaptics code through ROS, it doesn't.

Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Thanks.

Following are some additional details:

$ echo $PATH
/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

and

$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/tufail/electric_workspace/sandbox/phantom:/opt/ros/electric/stacks

The following Debian packages have already been installed but ROS can't find them:

```
freeglut3-dev
libdrm-dev
libexpat1-dev
libglw1-mesa
libmotif-dev
libncurses5-dev
libx11-dev
libxt-dev    
tcsh
x11proto-dri2-dev
x11proto-gl-dev
x11proto-print-dev
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59228/can-we-merge-%7B1e67e555-353f-4764-9f00-cedd09225d9d%7Dros_package_path???/) by [tufail](https://answers.ros.org/users/4381/tufail/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-03-26**:
Hello, can you update your question to address the following? How are you running the code "through ROS"? What error messages are you getting?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-03-26**:
Can you clarify how ROS can't find the installed packages? Is there a specific compile error you're seeing, or does it only have trouble at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have resolved it.

As the packages (dependencies) were already installed using Ubuntu Software Centre, so ROS didn't need to re-install them. I just removed those rosdep entries from the manifest file in package and built it again. It worked.

Thanks for your replies anyway. I appreciate it.

---

Originally posted by [tufail](https://answers.ros.org/users/4381/tufail/) with karma: 18 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0